# MSSQL - row_number() in views display unexpected

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, row-number

I need to get row number from a view not changing the main select, but it displays the overall rownumber table insted of the selected row rumber.

Here's the values in table1:

```
field1
---------
aa
ab
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
```

I created a view like this:

```
select field1, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY field1) as rowno
from table1
```

but a select displays the overall rownumbers:

```
select *
from myview 
where field1 like 'c%'


field1      rowno
-----------------
ca          6
cb          7
cc          8
```

instead of

```
field1      rowno
-----------------
ca          1
cb          2
cc          3
```

any chance to get it right?

Comment: don't put the  `row_number` in the view. Put it in the select clause

Comment: As it is displayed, it IS right... you put the rowno into the view - and in the view, ca is in row 6 and cb in row 7... if you want YOUR result numbered, you will have to perform the rowno call outside of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you aren't getting the concept of row number right here. If you need row number to start from 1 everytime you are selecting from that view, you should not be selecting the row_number column that is already generated in the select statement of the view, instead, you must write your ROW_NUMBER() part of the condition in every select statement you run against the view.
You would need something like this:

```
SELECT fields1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY field1) as rowno
FROM <viewname>
WHERE fields1 LIKE 'C%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you need `subquery` instead :

```
select t.*
from (select field1, row_number() over (order by field1) as rowno
      from table1
     ) t
where field1 like 'c%';
```

Comment: i can't modify the main query, it's a select * made by an external program